# While derivating equations of motion, why do we replace $v$ as $u + at$?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

I was learning about the calculus derivations of equations of motion. After the derivation of $v=u + at$, where $v =$ final velocity and $u =$ initial velocity, came the 2nd Equation of motion.

In my book it is written as

> By definition of velocity,

> $v = dx/dt$

> $\Rightarrow  dx = vdt$

> In the above equation, $v$ is not independent of $t$. So we replace the value of $v$ by $v = u + at$.

What does the last line mean? I haven't learned integration in depth, just what is taught us in school. Can we not integrate dependent variables or something?

Comment: To obtain $x$ as a function of time by interesting $v$, you need $v$ as a function of time. Under constant acceleration, it has the form $v=u+at$ which, because it has concurrent $u,\,a$ is easily integrated to obtain $x=x_0+ut+\frac12at^2$.

Answer (score 2):

So they are postulating a form for $v(t)$, and this form is a constant one-dimensional acceleration. There are many other forms that acceleration may take but this is the “easiest”.

If you do not postulate a form, then you cannot simplify the expression $\int\mathrm dt~v(t)$. The expression is not wrong, but it's less useful if you do not know something about what $v(t)$ is.

Let me give you an example of what this looks like at a more advanced level.

So for example in free-fall in air you have a negative velocity in the $y$-direction upwards, hence an acceleration proportional to the *square of velocity*, so not constant. If we assume that the force of gravity and the density of the air are constant, then we are postulating a particular form for the acceleration,
$$
\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt} = -g~\left[1 - \left(\frac{v(t)}{v_\text{term}}\right)^2\right]
$$
where the terminal velocity $v_\text{term}$ is determined by a lot of other parameters, and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.

This can then be separated and integrated, let $\tau = t~g/v_\text{term}$, $u(\tau) = v(t)/v_\text{term}$, then we get the unit-less form $$
\int\frac{\mathrm du}{1-u^2} = -\tau$$
This can be integrated by the hyperbolic trig functions, assuming v(0)=0 gives $$ v(t) = -v_\text{term}~\tanh\left({g~t\over v_\text{term}}\right)$$
and now we could solve for $y(t)$ with $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt = v(t), y(0) =y_0,$ to model a skydiver’s altitude as
$$ y(t) = y_0 - \frac{v_\text{term}^2}{g}~\ln\left[\cosh\left({g~t\over v_\text{term}}\right)\right].$$

These are all integrals that maybe your second calculus course would teach you to do, they're not that complicated once you have some experience. But, you don't have much experience! So they started with the case of constant acceleration, which will lead to a characteristic $\frac12$ factor that they want to get you used to. Constant acceleration is just $\mathrm dv/\mathrm dt=a,$ integrating we get $v(t)=v_0+at$.

Constant acceleration is usually a really good place to start! For instance in the above expression for very small values of q, $\cosh(q)\approx 1+\frac12 q^2$ and similarly $\ln(1+q)\approx 1 + q$, you can combine these approximations together to find that for very small times $t$, $y(t) = y_0 - \frac12 g t^2,$ which is precisely the constant acceleration equation with $v_0=0$ and $a=-g.$ If you work to quantify what “small” means here, say a deviation of 10% is “small”, then this  constant acceleration equation describes about the first 4s of free-fall or about the first 70-80 meters, not bad!

Answer (score 0):

The last line simply gives a particular form of the time dependence of velocity, say $v=u+at$, so that readers can use it as an example to practice. You may play with other velocity-time relations, say "$v=at^2 $" to derive interesting (sorry the example I give is not so interesting, but still suitable for beginners in calculus" position-time relation.